# Importing gdal in QGIS and PyCharm not working

Tags: qgis, gdal, pycharm

Trying to import gdal from osgeo and I'm getting this error;

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: The specified module could not be found.

On Windows, with Python >= 3.8, DLLs are no longer imported from the PATH.
If gdalXXX.dll is in the PATH, then set the USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON=YES environment variable
to feed the PATH into os.add_dll_directory().
```

I have seen this error referenced in a number of places but no solution that I can see, some suggest using conda or miniconda to make a virtual environment but that isn't an option for me. I just want to be able to use gdal from my QGIS python console and pyCharm console directly.

What does this error mean?
How can I set my USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON=YES? Do I use OSGeo4W Shell? Do I need to edit a BAT file?
How is os.add_dll_directory() used to feed the PATH? What PATH is it looking for?
Am I just importing gdal incorrectly with from osgeo import gdal? Is there another way to import gdal?
OS Windows 10, OSGeo4W installed on C:, QGIS 3.22.6, PyCharm 2021.1.1, Python3.9(C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In using this guide
https://spatialgalaxy.net/2018/02/13/quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis3-on-windows/
I was able to create a bat file that when run loads all the proper paths for

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W :: Change this to OSGeo4w or OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-7.4.0\etc\env.bat :: "grass-7.4.0" will need to be replaced with your grass version in ...apps\grass Newer versions use grass78 or grass80
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.4.0\lib :: See note on grass versions
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W3\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W3\apps\Python36\Scripts :: Python36 references will need to be changed, newer versions use Python39

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36 :: See python note

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%

cmd.exe :: Delete this line and add 'start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B "PATHTOPYCHARM.exe"'
```

Run the bat file and you should get a PyCharm running with OSGeo4W paths and a working osgeo and gdal, you need to import gdal from osgeo

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

Comment: That guide is ancient, outdated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: <QGIS-dir>\bin\python-qgis[-ltr].bat

Comment: But the process works, just needs to be updated for newer versions of QGIS.

Comment: Better trust the QGIS developers who do exactly that with the `<QGIS-dir>\bin\python-qgis[-ltr].bat` file! No one needs to manually build or copy-paste these lines anymore.

Comment: Perhaps then you could update the answer with your preferred way of getting Pycharm to work with QGIS.

Answer (score -1):

I took the error message as an instruction and did the following.

Firstly, I tried to add the custom environment variable `USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON`

[image: environment variable USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON]

The error message changed a bit, but it still complained about gdalXXX.dll.

So, I opened the `C:\OSGeo4W` folder and searched in it for `gdal*.dll`

[image: OSGeo4W folder search for gdal*.dll]

Then I manually copied all these folders paths and added them to my Path.

[image: User Path]

Here they are, 4 folders.

[image: OSGeo4W gdal folders in Path]

Now `from osgeo import gdal` works.

[image: from osgeo import gdal]